# Values of Two Textboxes on Another Page PHP

Tags: php

Good Day,

I have a textbox and I am fetching its value in next page.

Pls see code first below

View.php

```
echo '<td class="forscreen"><a href="equipments.php?emp_number=' .$row['emp_number'] . '">Add Accessories</a></td>';
```

When you click add accessories, you get value of emp_number on next page where on next page I have:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="emp_numberPrint" id="emp_number" readonly value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['emp_number'])) ? htmlentities($_GET['emp_number']) : ''; ?>"/>
```

Now, I want the same if I have another textbox named owner and I am trying the below code:

```
echo '<td class="forscreen"><a href="equipments.php?emp_number=' .$row['emp_number'] .$row['first_name'] . '">Add Accessories</a></td>';

<input class="input" type="text" name="ownerPrint" readonly value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['ownerPrint'])) ? htmlentities($_GET['first_name']) : ''; ?>"/>
```

Here first_name is to be fetched from last page in same way as emp_number is coming but it is not working,

Surely I am making mistake. Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: isset($_GET['ownerPrint'] ) not get in second case

Comment: I know I tried even first_name also not working

Comment: It's a little unclear what all your pages are and how you navigate through them. Where are ownerPrint and first_name getting set? What is "not working" about it?

Comment: See very first line.. Add acceossories href is clickec right?when you click, it goes to next page and value of emp_number is set by default which was in view.php  .. Same I want for first_name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your approach, you have to pass it in query string to get this on next page.

For View.php

```
echo '<td class="forscreen"><a href="equipments.php?emp_number=' .$row['emp_number'] .'&first_name='.$row['first_name'] . '">Add Accessories</a></td>';
```

On the next page

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="ownerPrint" readonly value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['first_name'])) ? htmlentities($_GET['first_name']) : ''; ?>"/>
```

Comment: By your code I am getting this in one textbox 10486first_name=Mazhar Iqbal
This first name I want in first name textbox separately which is below emp_number textbox

Comment: I forgot to add `&` at first, but now it is corrected. So try again.

Comment: can you please answer my question here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696907/creating-radiobutton-in-front-end-php

Answer (score 0):

In Second Case

```
 echo '<td class="forscreen">
<a href="equipments.php?emp_number=' .$row['emp_number'].$row['first_name'] . '">
Add Accessories</a></td>';
```

You are passing the values wrongly
You must pass the variables like this

```
 <a href="equipments.php?emp_number=<?php echo $row['emp_number'];  ?>
&first_name=<?php echo $row['first_name'] ; ?>">
Add Accessories</a>
```

you can get values in next page is like

```
$_GET['emp_number'];
$_GET['first_name'];
```