# Creating RadioButton in Front end (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Good Day!

What I want is that I am having 3 radio buttons and a button in the end which is clicked to create new radio button where user enters label and value and check/uncheck himself.

I a trying below code :

JS:

```
function createRadioElement( name, checked ) {
var radioInput;
try {
    var radioHtml = '<input type="radio" name="' + name + '"';
    if ( checked ) {
        radioHtml += ' checked="checked"';
    }
    radioHtml += '/>';
    radioInput = document.createElement(radioHtml);
} catch( err ) {
    radioInput = document.createElement('input');
    radioInput.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    radioInput.setAttribute('name', name);
    if ( checked ) {
        radioInput.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    }
}

return radioInput;
}
```

In Div:

```
<input type="button" name="create" value="Create New Equipment" onclick="javascript:createRadioElement();"></label><br />
```

It is created in my div named form_div

Please Guide

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: No Error but radiobutton not created

Comment: I think your `createRadioElement()` function is looking for two parameters, which is not being provided in your `onclick="javascript:createRadioElement();"`

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana Logan has a point.

Comment: This am saying.. I want to create radio button with label itself but am not getting idea how to put it there in js and div

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana Use a textbox?

Comment: Yes I can use but where would I? and will Textbox convert to radio after creating and will it stay on page? because i created one but on page refresh it was disappearing

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana Sorry I can't help you out here.

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana - I will try to provide an answer in a bit.

Comment: @AJ  NO issue dear :)

Comment: @LoganWayne Thanks :)

Comment: @AJ Can you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738053/radiobutton-created-dynamically-to-be-inserted-in-db-php-using-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Solution:

What you can do, with your current condition, is to put the needed parameters inside the function of your `onclick` tags.

```
onclick="javascript:createRadioElement('new option', 'checked');"
```

### Problem:

But the problem is that the new option will be fix, depending on what you hard-code in the first parameter.

### New Solution:

What you can do, is to add a text box right before your button, so you can give the user the chance to input their preferred option.

```
<div id="option-div"></div> <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE NEW RADIO BUTTONS WILL BE PUT -->
<input type="text" id="new-option" placeholder="Insert New Option">
<input type="button" id="create" value="Create New Equipment">
```

Then, create a script that will create a new radio button, along with the input text of the user:

```
var optiondiv = document.getElementById('option-div'); /* GET THE DIV ELEMENT OF WHERE WE WILL PUT THE RADIO BUTTONS */

document.getElementById('create').onclick = function () { /* WHEN CREATE NEW EQUIPMENT BUTTON IS CLICKED */

    var input = document.createElement('input'), /* CREATE NEW INPUT ELEMENT */
        newopt = document.getElementById('new-option').value; /* GET THE INPUT OF THE USER */
        label = document.createElement('label'); /* CREATE A NEW LABEL ELEMENT */

    /* IF USER DID NOT INPUT A TEXT, 'No Entered Text' WILL BE THE DEFAULT VALUE */
    newopt = (newopt == '')?'No Entered Text':newopt;

    /* FILL OUT THE TAGS OF THE NEW INPUT ELEMENT */
    input.type = "radio";
    input.setAttribute("value", newopt);
    input.setAttribute("checked", true);
    input.setAttribute("name", "radio-name");

    /* PUT THE INPUT ELEMENT/RADIO BUTTON INSIDE THE LABEL */
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.innerHTML += newopt+'<br>';

    /* PUT THE LABEL ELEMENT INSIDE THE option-div DIV */
    optiondiv.appendChild(label);

    document.getElementById('new-option').value = ''; /* RESET THE TEXT FIELD */

};
```

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/k3vuwf2v/) for an example.

---

### The real problem:

You want to store the newly added radio buttons permanently, but you resorted first in Javascript.

### Solution:

To store the newly added radio buttons permanently, you can it store it in your database. You have to structure a database that will make your form dynamic.

Create a table, lets say `radio_tb`:

```
radio_id | name |
---------+------+
    1    | opt1 |
    2    | opt2 |
    3    | opt3 |
```

Then, try to display them as radio buttons:

```
/* ASSUMING YOU ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION TO $connection VARIABLE */
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT radio_id, name FROM radio_tb");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($radioid, $name);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<label><input type="radio" name="equip" value="'.$radioid.'">'.$name.'</label>';
}
$stmt->close();
```

You can continue using the script I have provided for inserting new radio button, but you have to use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to insert those newly added options into your database.

Comment: Textbox is there and shown with a button. When I clicked button, nothing happened

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana - Are you talking about the fiddle? Try to refresh the page. Wait for it to load properly. Then, try to test the program.

Comment: The JSfiddle that I have provided? The link that I have provided? That is weird. I've tried on Chrome and IE, both working. Or are you pertaining on your local work with the code I have given? This is not working on your browser - [https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/k3vuwf2v/](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/k3vuwf2v/)?

Comment: I am getting textbox and button and when I enter value like abc in textbox suppose then after clicking button, nothing happens, No radio button is added. I have added script you have under <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: O I got it.. I copied <div id="option-div"></div> <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE NEW RADIO BUTTONS WILL BE PUT -->

and did not add radio button here :)
let me try again :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you are referring to my JSfiddle that is not working. To troubleshoot, just check your console log for errors. Hit F12 if you are using Google Chrome as your browser.

Comment: I have this code

<div id="option-div">
     <br /><label>Printer <input type="radio" id="printCheck" name="equip" value="printer" onclick="javascript:radioCheck();"></label>
     <label>Telephone <input type="radio" id="phoneCheck" name="equip" value="phone" onclick="javascript:radioCheck();"></label><br />
         
     </div> 
     <input type="text" id="new-option" placeholder="Insert New Option">
     <input type="button" id="create" value="Create New Equipment">

But textbox is shown but button click gives no radio .. Donno why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124187/discussion-between-logan-wayne-and-mazhar-iqbal-rana).

Comment: this new addition of code I have to add in db file?
Or in my code php file where radio buttons are

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create new element with jquery or something?

There is no single line of PHP code here or mySQL there.

If you're trying to append radio button on client side, you need jquery
And if you need user to enter label / check or uncheck himself, you supposely need input text and checkbox.

If it's just about appending radio button, this should works

```
<html>
<div id="data">
   <!--THIS IS 3 YOUR 3 RADIO BUTTONS-->
   <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="radiobutton">radiobutton</input><br />
   <input type="radio" name="name" value="name">name</input><br />
   <input type="radio" name="checked" value="checked">checked</input><br />
   <input type="button" id="button" name="create" value="Create New Equipment">
</div>
<!--This is where you load your jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //This is your Button Handler (if you use jquery you dont need to create a js function)
   $("#button").click(function(){
       var radioHtml = '<input type="radio" name="' + name + '"';
       if ( $("#checked").checked ) {
          radioHtml += ' checked="checked"';
       }
       radioHtml += '>test</name>';
       //This is line where you append your code on your html on div with id data
       $("#data").append(radioHtml);
   });
</script>
</html>
```

Here is the result

[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCrC1.png)

[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibLht.png)

Your question is hard to understand though, maybe you can elaborate more.

Comment: Well this I was able to do but issue is. It should remain. try your code and reload the page. created ones will be lost..

Comment: @fadeltd - And OP is using the standard Javascript, not a library of Javascript - jQuery.

Comment: @MazharIqbalRana yes, the object is created on click not on page load, so it would disappear once you reload the page, which one do you want actually? and where would you like to enter your label? so you need input text?

Comment: @fadeltd Yes Then how will they be shown or saved in db? This I want It shows but not is saved in DB